# Setting a custom variable in magento transactional emails

Tags: transactional-mail

What I want to achieve is to add a custom variable in the header, which displays me if I am on account related template to show "Account" or if I am on invoice template to show "Invoice" and so on.
I read this [article](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/transactional-emails-variable-magento/) and I didn't find this kind of variable.
Is there a way to create this kind of variable:

`{{ var custom_email_name }}`

?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a function which is responsible for sending letters in magento:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional()
```

Here is params list:

```
/**
 * Send transactional email to recipient
 *
 * @param   int $templateId
 * @param   string|array $sender sender information, can be declared as part of config path
 * @param   string $email recipient email
 * @param   string $name recipient name
 * @param   array $vars variables which can be used in template
 * @param   int|null $storeId
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 *
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
 */
```

5th param `$vars`, which contain values for output in template. It can contain simple variables or objects. E.g. order object or customer object. In that case you can call methods of these objects inside templates.

For example {{var order.getId}} return order ID.

So in your case you need to find where this method calls and add new variable/object and then call inside template. Or if can be covered by calling existing method - you can do it without any method call modification.

**Upd.1**

For invoice this function is using:

[image]

And here is $vars variable:

[image]

Comment: are u sure that the sendTransctional function is responsible for displaying the template?. I put an exit in the beginning of the fc, and nothing happens when I press the preview button .

Comment: Which email do you want to send?

Comment: For example for new invoice, order invoice ... I want that my variabile contains the value "Invoice", for  any account related temaplate(pass. recovery, new account...) i want that my variable contains the value "acccount".

Comment: Updated.........

Comment: If you still don't know how to resolve your problem, do not hesitate to ask more questions. Maybe if you more specify your question - it would be more easy to answer. E.g. I'd like to add to ..... template  this ...... variable